# Password Stored in the memory

Tags: iphone, ios

During the login request, password get stored. After this request I'm setting the password string with an empty character. 
Does it really store in memory, if it does how would I check? And how do I wipe that off.

I'm already using ARC in my App.

Comment: Please describe your issue with code. The description above really not sufficient to understand your issue.

Comment: -(id)getLoginReqService:(NSString *)password
{
    NSString *loginRequest = [self ChooseLoginRequest:password];

 LOGIN REQUETS
 password = @"";
    return self;
}

Comment: Above way I'm using to set the password in a string. Does this actually store in memory ?

Comment: Also you can store the password int keychain to store username and password http://goo.gl/OLAEl

Comment: This code will now store the string into memory at all.

Comment: If you want to wipe it off then in ARC use this line [password setString:nil];  It'll set password string to nil.

Comment: [password setString:nil]; if at all I use this what happens to the password string memory, will that be erased ??

Comment: @iCreative ... Now I have set as password = nil; So this will now wipe off the password string memory right. Will this work ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Stroe user information
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"Moses" forKey:@"username"];
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"age"];
[prefs synchronize];

//Getting the stored information
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *username = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];
NSInteger age = [prefs integerForKey:@"age"];
```

Storing a password in NSUserDefaults is insecure, since anyone who get access to the iPhone, can view the password.

Comment: I'm not storing it in NSUserDefaults , I'm storing it in a string. So let me know if this is stored in memory, if its stored then how do I wipe that String memory..

Comment: That means are you want to overwrite with old value

Comment: yes.. I'm already doing it for the string. I'm setting this string as password = @"" , just want to know the actual password will stored in memory or the next empty character which is set.

Comment: i think please insert the username and password store into the NSUserDefaults so it's easy to access from whole project like global variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the string is empty..via

```
if([yourString isEqualToString:@""]){
NSLog(@"empty string");
}
```

Comment: If at all I set password = nil , then what will be stored in memory ?